# How to schedule a cron job in appengine if cron job requires authentication(username and password)

Tags: google-app-engine

How to schedule a cron job in app engine if cron job requires authentication(username and password).
It is not good practice to send username and password in the url tag in cron.xml.
So is there a way to do it?

Thanks,
Damodar

Comment: Do you mean that the authentication is required for the cron job to be able to access certain resources (outbound connections) or for protecting the very execution of the cron job itself?

Comment: yes Dan, i need the authentication for the URL we will add in cron file. And how cron job will take care of authentication.

Answer (score -1):

You can test for `HTTP_USER_AGENT` in the request.  For example, in Python/Django:

```
if 'AppEngine-Google' in request.META.get('HTTP_USER_AGENT', ''):
```

And let the cron job bypass the login.

Also, if the url requires `login:admin` in your app.yaml, then the cron job automatically satisfies the requirement.